# getting error for the following junit test case using jpa

Tags: jpa, junit

The following is my junit test case using jpa

```
package com.msat.srt.dao;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.List;



import javax.persistence.EntityManager;  
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;  
import javax.persistence.Persistence;  
import javax.persistence.Query;

import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;  
import org.apache.log4j.Level;  
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;  
import org.junit.Before;  
import org.junit.BeforeClass;  
import org.junit.Ignore;  
import org.junit.Test;  


import com.msat.srt.vo.MarvalUpdateVO;

public class MarvalUpdateEJBTest {

      private static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "SRTEJB";
      private static EntityManagerFactory emf;
      private EntityManager em;

    @BeforeClass
        public static void initializeLogging() {
          BasicConfigurator.configure();
          Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR);
        }

    @Before
      public void setUp() throws Exception {
         emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
         em = emf.createEntityManager();

     }
    @Test
    public void testGetAllTicketTypes() {

        Query qry = em.createQuery("select tb from TblSrtttypemaster tb");
        assertTrue(qry.getResultList().size() == 4);
          }

    }
```

i'm getting the following error message.. i dont't know how to rectify it. Do i need to include properties of db connection again in the above test class??

```
    java.lang.ClassFormatError: 

        Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/validation/Validation   

        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)   
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)  
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)  
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)  
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)  
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)  
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)  
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)  
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at org.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:170)    
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationActivator.applyDDL    (BeanValidationActivator.java:103)    
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.applyBeanValidationConstraintsOnDDL     (Configuration.java:1674)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.applyConstraintsToDDL(Configuration.java:1624)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1415)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1345)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildMappings(Ejb3Configuration.java:1477)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.EventListenerConfigurator.configure(EventListenerConfigurator.java:193)    
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:1096)    
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:278)    
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:362)    
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:56)   
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:48)   
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:32)
        at com.msat.srt.dao.MarvalUpdateEJBTest.setUp(MarvalUpdateEJBTest.java:43)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)    
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)    
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

I am using JPA and this is my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="SRTEJB" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/srt</jta-data-source>

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.WebSphereExtendedJTATransactionLookup"/>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/> 
    </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem of use one of the dependencies

```
<dependency>  
   <groupId>javax</groupId>  
   <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>  
   <version>6.0</version>  
</dependency> 

OR

<dependency>  
   <groupId>javax</groupId>  
   <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>  
   <version>6.0</version>  
</dependency>
```

As state [here](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/WhatsTheCauseOfThisExceptionJavalangClassFormatErrorAbsentCode):

> This dependency provides you with the Java EE APIs, not the implementations. While this dependency works for compiling, it cannot be used for executing code (that includes tests).

One solution from [mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/java-lang-classformaterror-absent-code-attribute-in-method-that-is-not-native-or-abstract-in-class-file/):

> The good practice is always get the original full version of javaee.jar file from the http://java.sun.com/javaee/. Just download and install the J2EE SDK, and the javaee.jar can be found in the “\J2EE_SDK_FOLDER\lib” folder. Include it into your local Maven repository or poject classpath will get rid of the above error message.

Another solution offered by [community.jboss](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/WhatsTheCauseOfThisExceptionJavalangClassFormatErrorAbsentCode):

> The other solution, which actually applies in both cases, is to use the Java EE spec artifact provided by [server vendor], for example

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

You can [search related issues](https://www.google.com.kh/?gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=YF-ZU6zHDITg8AWs0ILwCw#q=Absent+Code+attribute+in+method+that+is+not+native+or+abstract+in+class+file+javax%2Fvalidation%2FValidation+). Though the the "Absent Code" may not be the same, you'll find that the problem is cause mainly by the "empty" javaee-api jar